# How to Query in django ORM for foreign key fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Employee(models.Model):
    dept  = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

Django ORM: Here I want to access `name` through Employee class in Django ORM.

```
I wrote something like this:  `Employee.objects.filter(name = dept__Company)`(Used two double underscore for other model class)
```

Will above is correct? Can someone have any idea?

Comment: I'm curious, do your fields really have the `.`'s in them? Im surprised that would work... Please show example code that actually represents your models `ForeignField` isn't a valid class either

Comment: No.That is a complex application.Just for sample i wrote like this.Any way i ll change the fields. Please see Question again..

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you're just trying to retrieve the employees that belong to a certain company. To do that you can just use either of these.

```
my_company_instance.employee_set.all()
Employee.objects.filter(dept__name=my_company_instance)
```

Personally, I prefer the first method.

For more information, you can see [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: Thats great. Actually i want to apply order_by on 'name' field. But i don't have the name field in Employee table.So i don't know how to proceed...

Comment: @danny - Its the same essentially, all querysets use the form `field_name__related_field_name` so you probably want `.order_by('dept__name')` (or `'-dept__name'` for reversed ordering)

Comment: @danny You can see result sql by calling `.query` property of any queryset object. e.g. 
`print Employee.objects.filter(dept__name='company_name').order_by('dept__name').query`

Comment: @crash843   If my model class 'Company' is present in a different API of my application(that means not present on same models.py) then how to access name by the help of employee model class?

Comment: @danny Not sure that i understood correctly, can you paste some code?