# How to order by a particular field in two different apps of two different table

Tags: django, django-models

I have two apps 1.app1 2.app2
 In each app i have a models.py file

**1st-models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):

    name = models.ForeignKey('dept',unique=True, max_length=64)
    empid = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=64)
```

**2nd Models.py**

```
class dept(models.Model):

    deptid = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=64)
    ident = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=64)
```

Here i am writing a django ORM to order_by deptid. I have employee table.

```
Employee.objects.all().orderby(name__dept__deptid)
```

I am confused how to queryset this. Can some one lend a helping hand!!!

Comment: `deptid` is a charfield so it won't have any fields of its own, please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: Use the real variable names. Naming your models `app1` and `app2` makes it very confusing.

Comment: @Alasdair See the question again...

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
Employee.objects.order_by('name__deptid')
```

Note that `order_by` has an underscore. The argument is of the form `<fk_field_name>_<field_name_on_other_model>`. It is the name of the foreign key field `name` that is important - the app name and model name do not matter.

Comment: For full disclosure, I sort of suggested this in the [op's last question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36454467/1324033) (I have no idea what they're after)

Comment: @Alasdair  If i eant to jump to another model which contains a foreign key as well then i also need to give '__fieldname'?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You might find [these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) helpful.